# Flex of table not working in Firefox, but works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

The html code below properly flexes the top table and displays a vertical scroll bar in Safari and Chrome.  However, in Firefox the top table is not flexing.  Can someone help me uncover what I am missing?

I have posted a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/trstaley/v1sabu6b/).

Open the jsfiddle in Chrome or Safari and it works.  Open it in Firefox and it does not.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Below is the code

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 100% !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
html {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html,
body,
.viewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#master_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 1160px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: auto;
}
#top_wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 885px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}
.banner_position {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #2483d0;
  width: 280px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}
#window_wrapper {
  min-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom;
  70px;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#bottom-wrapper {
  height: 34px;
  min-width: 885px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #000;
}
 :focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=button] {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
#window_wrapper {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#wrapper_1 {
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrapper_2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.sub_wrapper_1 {
  min-width: 478px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.table_1_wrapper {
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
}
.table_wrapper {
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.table_header {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 18px;
}
.table_header span {} .select_all {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.button_padding {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.table_2_header {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 1px;
  text-align: left;
}
.table_2_header span {
  display: inline-block;
}
.fixed_table_wrapper {
  max-height: 103px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
td {
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
}
.table_wrapper td.fixed {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
.table_wrapper td.flex {
  width: 74%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}
.table_header_inner {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}
.table_2_header_inner {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="master_wrapper">
  <div id="top_wrapper" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-widget ui-widget-content custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  </div>

  <div id="window_wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper_1">
      <div class="sub_wrapper_1">
        <div class="table_1_wrapper">
          <div class="table_header ui-widget-header">
            <div class="table_header_inner">
              <span class="group_cb">&nbsp;</span><span class="name_header_pos">Title 1</span><span class="member_header_pos">Title 2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table_wrapper">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r1</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r2</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r3</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r4</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r5</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r6</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r7</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r8</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r9</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r10</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r11</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r12</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r13</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r14</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="flex">r15</td>
                  <td class="fixed">1</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper_2">
      <div class="table_2_header ui-widget-header">
        <div class="table_header_inner">
          <span class="group_cb">&nbsp;</span><span class="name_header_pos">Title 1</span><span class="member_header_pos">Title 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed_table_wrapper">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r1</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r2</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r3</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r4</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r5</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r6</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r7</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r8</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r9</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r10</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r11</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r12</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r13</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r14</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="flex">r15</td>
              <td class="fixed">1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="select_all">
        <input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" class="select_all_btn">
        <label>Select All</label>
        <div class="button_padding">
          <input type="button" name="delete_sent" id="delete_sent" value="Delete" class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only'>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-wrapper" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header"></div>
```

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `#window_wrapper`. https://jsfiddle.net/v1sabu6b/1/